# How to create index on huge oracle table?

Tags: oracle

I tried it with below SQL.

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON table1 (column1, column2) Local parallel 10;
```

but its giving me below error

> ```
> SQL Error: ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server ..,
> instance .. ORA-27090: Unable to reserve kernel resources for
> asynchronous disk I/O Additional information: 3 Additional
> information: 128 Additional information: -1374056344
> 12801. 00000 -  "error signaled in parallel query server %s"
> *Cause:    A parallel query server reached an exception condition.
> *Action:   Check the following error message for the cause, and consult
>            your error manual for the appropriate action.
> *Comment:  This error can be turned off with event 10397, in which
>            case the server's actual error is signaled instead. 
> Elapsed: 00:16:10.821
> ```

where `table1` is a partitioned table.

Comment: Is it a partitionized table?

Comment: yes it is partitioned.

Comment: What is the oracle version you are using 12c or 11g?

Comment: Did you try with a lower `parallel` value? e.g. `parallel 4`?

Answer (score 8):

You can try to build the index individually for each partition:

```
BEGIN
    FOR aPart IN (SELECT PARTITION_NAME FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE1') LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE TABLE1 MODIFY PARTITION '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME||' INDEXING OFF';
    END LOOP;   
END;
/

CREATE INDEX TABLE1 ON idx (column1, column2) LOCAL INDEXING PARTIAL;

BEGIN
    FOR aPart IN (SELECT PARTITION_NAME FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE1') LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER INDEX idx REBUILD PARTITION '||aPart .PARTITION_NAME||' PARALLEL 10';
    END LOOP;   
END;
/

-- Enable indexing, otherwise new partitions will not get indexed.
ALTER TABLE TABLE1 MODIFY DEFAULT ATTRIBUTES INDEXING ON;
```